# glUniform1i has no effect

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, opengl-3

I am trying to assign texture unit 0 to a `sampler2D` uniform but the uniform's value does not change.

My program is coloring points based on their elevation (Y coordinates). Their color is looked up in a texture.

Here is my vertex shader code :

```c
#version 330 core

#define ELEVATION_MODE

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in float intensity;

uniform mat4 vpMat;

flat out vec4 f_color;

#ifdef ELEVATION_MODE
    uniform sampler2D elevationTex;
#endif

#ifdef INTENSITY_MODE
    uniform sampler2D intensityTex;
#endif

// texCoords is the result of calculations done on vertex coords, I removed the calculation for clarity
vec4 elevationColor() {
    return vec4(textureLod(elevationTex, elevationTexCoords, 0), 1.0);
}

vec4 intensityColor() {
    return vec4(textureLod(elevationTex, intensityTexCoords, 0), 1.0);
}

int main() {
    gl_Position = vpMat * vec4(position.xyz, 1.0);


    #ifdef ELEVATION_MODE
        f_color = elevationColor();
    #endif

    #ifdef COLOR_LODDEPTH
        f_color = getNodeDepthColor();
    #endif
}
```

Here is my fragment shader :

```c
#version 330 core

out vec4 color;

flat in vec4 f_color;

void main() {
    color = f_color;
}
```

When this shader is executed, I have 2 textures bound :

1. elevation texture in texture unit 0
2. intensity texture in texture unit 1

I am using `glUniform1i` to set the uniform's value :

```
glUniform1i(elevationTexLocation, (GLuint)0);
```

But when I run my program, the value of the uniform `elevationTex` is `1` instead of `0`.

If I remove the `glUniform1i` call, the uniform value does not change (still 1) so I think the call is doing nothing (but generates no error).

If I change the uniform's type to `float` and the call from `glUniform1i` to :

```
glUniform1f(elevationYexLocation, 15.0f);
```

The value in the uniform is now `15.0f`. So there is no problem in my program with the location from which I call `glUniform1i`, it just has no impact on the uniform's value.

Any idea about what I could be doing wrong ?

I could give you more code but it is not really accessible so if you know the answer without it that's great. If you need the C++ part of the code, ask, I'll try to retrieve the important parts

Comment: Why do you use `elevationTex` in `intensityColor`? *"But when I run my program, the value of the uniform `elevationTex` is 1 instead of 0."* - How do you know that? How do you load the textures to the GPU and when do you bind them to the texture units?

Comment: I use elevationTex in intensityColor because I failed my copy paste. Good catch.
I know my textures are bound & I know the value of the uniform because I debugged my program in apitrace. The values of the uniforms returned by apitrace never changes (always 1). If I bind elevationTex to 1 instead of 0, it works (but that's not a solution)

Comment: Are you really sure about that. Do you something like, 1. load  `elevationTex`; 2. bind `elevationTex` to unit 0; 3. load `intensityTex`; 4. bind `intensityTex` to unit 1? In this case `intensityTex` may be bound to unit 0 and unit 1.

Comment: No, I load both textures at start-up, I bound them both once per frame (so way later in the program lifetime).

Comment: Silly question, but the program is installed when you set the uniform, isn't it? - This means  `glUseProgram` is done before `glUniform1i`?

Comment: Yes, it is installed when I call `glUniform1i`

I found the problem. It was my mistake. I had a uniform location that was not initialized (so undefined value) and I was assigning another uniform to it (nothing to do with the textures).
I do not know what happens when a value is assigned to a uniform location that does not exist in the shader but is seems to have overwritten my uniform1i.